# derive consumer expenditure function without solving directly for Hicksian demand

Tags: microeconomics

On the image (  https://prnt.sc/0jYC5khEFyok), I am stuck. How could I proceed to solve the "E"   with blue arrow and derive the **consumer expenditure function** without solving directly for Hicksian demand ?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you basically have it

$\overline{u}=(\frac{1}{4p_x})^{1/4}(\frac{3}{4p_y})^{3/4}*E(p_x,p_y,\overline{u})$

Move everything but $E$ to the left hand side and you have

$$E(p_x,p_y,\overline{u})=\overline{u}\cdot(\frac{1}{4p_x})^{-1/4}\cdot(\frac{3}{4p_y})^{-3/4}$$